# Did select on table view cell does not response

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, webview

The problem is that I have a tableview with webview 
Inside each cell and the content of webview can scroll 
Horizontally, but not vertically. It’s height is the same as
Cells height. So the problem is when I am trying to detect 
DidSelect of tableview cell it doesn’t response. But when I tried to put userinteraction of webview to false it works but webview can not scroll anymore. Is there any alternative ways of doing this. Btw webview cells must contain webview no other ways. 
Here is the screenshot of why I need webview inside cell. 
[Each cell contains webview content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYNwJ.jpg)

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: The touch input is going to WebView so you won't get any didSelect event here. Also what is the purpose of didSelect here?

Comment: I attached screenshot. And you can find that each cell has wenview and didselect is used to track option of quiz selection (single, multiple)

Answer (score 0):

You can add UITapGestureRecognizer to the WebView and do the action inside the UITapGestureRecognizer. (Here I'm adding how to add a gesture recognizer, you have to adapt it to your own case)

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: webView, action:  #selector(self.handleSingleTap(_:)))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Do something here with the gesture 
}
```

Comment: That worked, but for tapgesture to work for webview, target should be superclass and also return true for (shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith delegate function) of uiwebviewdelegate

Comment: @MKh If it helped you, fix my answer and set it as correct so it can help more people :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set delay touch false in order to have select event for cell.

`tableview.delaysContentTouches = false`

use this link for detail info - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches